# cookie/oauth issues

Tags: angularjs, trigger.io

I'm having some cookie/oauth issues. What I'm trying to achieve is have a new tab open up, have the user go through google's oauth flow, and upon returning to the app they should be able to make requests to our api with the cookie they receive, but.. I have no idea how to save that cookie. If I go into chrome's inspect tool I can see the cookie in the resources tab, but anything done with forge or angularjs (the js framework I'm using) doesn't include the cookie, and due to browser security I can't set it manually. Any help?

Comment: The oauth flows we've seen in action usually involve passing back an access token as the final step in the oauth process which can then be used as a parameter in subsequent API calls. Let us know more detail of your use case with code snippets and we can advise further. Here is our recipe for oauth: http://current-docs.trigger.io/features/modal.html

Comment: Ah I think the 'remote redirect' pattern described in the docs should work for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to save it as a cookie?  You have localStorage (or [forge.prefs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/prefs.html?highlight=prefs#prefs.set), but not sure how those work exactly).

You're in a mobile app, so the security of localStorage isn't a worry.

Answer (score 0):

I use angular-storage. It is perfect for storing the token.
https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage

To save your token after login:

```
      store.set('jwt', data.token);
      store.set('user', jwtHelper.decodeToken(store.get('jwt')));
```

Then to check if your token is valid:

```
  .run(function($rootScope, $state, store, jwtHelper) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
      if (toState.data && toState.data.requiresLogin) {

        store.set('redirect', {state: toState.name, stateParams: toParams});

        //TODO This is never passing but still redirecting?
        if (!store.get('jwt') || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(store.get('jwt'))) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $state.go('login');
        }
      }
    });
  })
```